# Как пунктуационно оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно пунктуационно оформить предложение:
"Кому-то может нравится, кому-то нет, но целостная теория сложилась..."?

Answer (score 1):

***Кому-то, может, нравится, кому-то нет, но целостная теория сложилась...*** и ***Кому-то, может, нравится, кому-то - нет, но целостная теория сложилась...*** При наличии паузы второй вариант тоже возможен. "Может" в обоих случаях - вводное слово и требует обособления.

***Если бы*** слово "нравится" было употреблено в форме инфинитива **"нравиться"**, то знаки требуются такие: ***Кому-то может нравитЬся, кому-то нет, но целостная теория сложилась...*** и ***Кому-то может нравитЬся, кому-то - нет, но целостная теория сложилась...*** В этом случае "может нравитЬся" - составное глагольное сказуемое.

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от правильности написания слова "нравится" Если оно написано правильно, то запятая нужна, т.к. "может" - вводное слово. Если же подразумевается инфинитив, то запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Если действительно хотите употребить слово "нравится", то лучше перестроить предложение, например так:

**Кому-то, возможно, это нравится, кому-то нет, но целостная теория сложилась...**

Если подразумевается инфинитив ("нравиться"), то запятая не нужна.